# Compare System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, date, time, compare

I want to compare two different time stamp using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Basically I want to check whether the time stamps are within 3 hours range on a particular day.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you expand *on a particular day*? Timestamp do not have the notion of "day", you also need a timezone. What should happen if, in a given timezone, you have 7th August 1 AM and 6th August 23PM?

Comment: Ah, of course the comment above should read *and 6th August 11PM*...

Comment: long time1, time2. ( (time1 - time2) / (60 * 60) ) // sec * mins . should get you the hour interval between them

Answer (score 6):

Considering you have `time1` and `time2`, where `time1 <= time2` you can do this:

```
if (time1 >= time2-(60*60*3*1000)) {
   // interval is up to 3 hours
} else {
   // interval is more than 3 hours
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Instant` to get the time in the epoch and convert it to `LocalDateTime` to get the information about the day and check, if the first time plus 3 hours is smaller than the second time:

```
long millis1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
long millis2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

Instant instant1 = Instant.EPOCH.plusMillis(millis1);
Instant instant2 = Instant.EPOCH.plusMillis(millis2);

LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant1, ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime t2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant2, ZoneId.systemDefault());

System.out.println("same day: " + (t1.getDayOfYear() == t2.getDayOfYear()));
System.out.println("t1+3h >= t2: " + (t1.plusHours(3).compareTo(t2) >= 0));
```

Comment: If i want to select rows from database table having one column with currentTimeMIllis() value stored in it. How can i perform above operation using sql query?

Comment: You simply get the `long` values from the database instead of `System.currentTimeMillis`. Furthermore you may need to adjust `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to use a different time zone, e.g. in case you're refering to `EDT(UTC-4:00)` but execute the code in europe...

Comment: Simpler to use `Instant.ofEpochMilli`. And when assigning a time zone use `ZonedDateTime`. The purpose of `LocalDateTime` is to *lose* time zone info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program that might help you out. The crux here is the method "findIfDatesWithinThreeHours" which helps whether to find if two instances are three hours apart.

```
package com.inrvu.adapter;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date[] dates = getTwoDatesThreeHoursApart();
    System.out.println(String.format("%b", findIfDatesWithinThreeHours(dates[0],dates[1])));

    dates = getTwoDatesWithinThreeHours();
    System.out.println(String.format("%b", findIfDatesWithinThreeHours(dates[0],dates[1])));
}

public static Date[] getTwoDatesThreeHoursApart()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date1 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,4);
    Date date2 = calendar.getTime();
    return new Date[]{date1,date2};
}

public static Date[] getTwoDatesWithinThreeHours()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date1 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,3);
    Date date2 = calendar.getTime();
    return new Date[]{date1,date2};
}

public static boolean findIfDatesWithinThreeHours(Date date1, Date date2) {
    // here the time of a single hour is defined as 60*60*1000
    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(date2);
    return Math.abs(date1.getTime()-date2.getTime()) <= 3*60*60*1000;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is vague. This might get you pointed in the right direction.

If by "timestamp" you meant a count of milliseconds since the epoch of 1970 UTC, [construct an `Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-). This class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds (finer than milliseconds).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millis );
```

Get current moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Calculate three hours.

```
Instant in3Hours = now.plus( 3 , ChronoUnit.HOURS );
```

See if your moment lies between now and three hours later.

```
Boolean contained = ( ( ! instant.isBefore( now ) ) && instant.isBefore( in3Hours ) );
```

If you meant you want to compare a pair of moments to see if the elapsed time is less than 3 hours, use a [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). This class represents a span of time in terms of seconds and nanoseconds.

```
Instant earlierInstant = … ;
Instant laterInstant = … ;
Duration duration = Duration.between( earlierInstant , laterInstant );
if ( duration.isNegative() ) { 
    … handle error of unexpected data inputs where the second instant is *before* the first instant.
}
… else …
Boolean elapsedUnderThreeHours = ( duration.compareTo( Duration.ofHours( 3 ) ) == -1 );
```